# Google OpenIdConnect People

Tags: google-oauth, google-openid, openid-connect

I implemented the client Side of OpenIDConnect authentication/provisioning/federation for few OAuth2-OpenIdConnect providers. But I fail to get Google OpenID People https://developers.google.com/+/api/openidconnect/getOpenIdConnect working.

I have no problem with the 1st part of OpenID Authentication/Authorization and get the Identity token from JSONWEBtoken without trouble. Nevertheless I fail to access the $identityApiUrl. The odd thing is that the old google's userinfo API works!!! Only the new one fails with an authorization error.

For PeopleAPI I used a Bearer token reusing the access_token, I got with my authorization request. Exactly like I do with the old API.

Here after a short extract from my code with the URL and scopes I used, as well as the error, I get when replaying manually with a curl the request.

Questions:

- Is there a special authentication method for OpenIdConnect People API ?
- Do I need to request special authorization in the application console ?

Extract from code with API's URL

```
    // main IDP configuration URLs
    protected $openidconnect = true;  // Google supports OpenID-Connect
    protected $authTokenUrl  = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth';
    protected $accessTokenUrl= 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token';
    // I fail to get Google People OpenIdConnect API to work :(
    //protected $identityApiUrl= 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/OpenIdConnect';
    protected $identityApiUrl= 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo';

    // OAuth2 action-1:  getAuthUrl($state) build authorization token url
    protected $scopes = ['openid','email','profile'];  // request authentication & email
```

**The error code, when replaying the request with curl**

```
[apache@vz-bzh GeoToBe]$ curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.5ABSl_75eP_zYFho_E-wVjPlZJc1XfY398HZqJjMxvRxBEWteLKZwNeh2v0BPwWuoH1iLpESeBQvFw" https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/openIdConnect
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
 }
}
```

Comment: Note that the Google+ APIs are all being deprecated in 2019.

Answer (score 4):

you need to enable the "Google+ API" under APIs & auth in the Google API console.

Comment: Thank you for this TIP, now it works. with both https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/openIdConnect and https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me